# How to define routes for loading previous component from the url which is having data?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, routerlink, angular-routerlink

Following are my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'nav',
    component:NavComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'basic-profile',
        component: BasicProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent
      },
      {
        path:'business-profile',
        component: BusinessProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path:'search/business-card-full-view/:businessAccountId',
        component: BusinessCardFullViewComponent,
      },
      {
        path:'messaging',
        component: MessagingComponent,
      }
   
    ]
  },
  
];
```

I am at URL

> http://localhost:4200/nav/search/business-card-full-view/10

```
     {
        path:'search/business-card-full-view/:businessAccountId',
        component: BusinessCardFullViewComponent,
      },
```

I want to go the

> http://localhost:4200/nav/messaging

```
     {
        path:'messaging',
        component: MessagingComponent,
      }
```

this URL by clicking one button.

```
<button mat-button routerLink="messaging">Message</button>
```

button is in BusinessCardFullViewComponent.

How can I do this?

I try **redirectTo** also

```
{
        path:'search/business-card-full-view/:businessAccountId',
        component: BusinessCardFullViewComponent,
        children:[
              {
                path:'messaging',
                redirectTo:'messaging',
              }
            ]
      },
```

But not working!

I do my work using Router as follows

```
messaging()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['nav/messaging']);
  }
```

It works..!

Comment: `routerLink="/nav/messaging"`? By using only `routerLink="messaging"`, you're asking for a [relative route](https://angular.io/guide/router#using-relative-paths) which resolves to `/nav/search/business-card-full-view/10/messaging` which isn't a valid route.

Comment: Yes but I try routerLink also but is do not work.